SQL PIVOT with SubCategories
Summary: I'm trying to use a SQL PIVOT to get Gender as a SubCategory of AgeBand (note, the age bands span two columns each). I've got AgeBand by itself working (see Below), but not sure how to add the second level (Gender) in a SQL PIVOT (SQL Server).



65-74
65-74
75-84
75-84




Female
Male
Female
Male


123
234
56
654


123
5345
456
76



I have a SQL Query that uses a PIVOT to get data from a table looking like this:



County
AgeBand
Gender
Section
Code
Desc
Count
Percent




ATLANTIS
65-74
F
13. General
F34
Apple
279
0.089


ATLANTIS
65-74
M
13. General
H84
Orange
166
0.053


ATLANTIS
65-74
F
13. General
W234
Pear
8
0.003


ATLANTIS
75-84
M
13. General
U7
Plum
541
0.261


ATLANTIS
65-74
M
13. General
V467
Peach
2
0.001



...and so on...
To look like this (counts and percents pivoted on the Age Bands):



County
Section
Code
Desc
Overall
Overall
65-74
65-74
75-84
75-84
85+
85+




-
-
-
-
Count
%
Count
%
Count
%
Count
%


ATLANTIS
13. General
F34
Apple
876
5
74
3
96
1
9
2


ATLANTIS
13. General
H84
Orange
876
7
67
7
86
4
6
1


ATLANTIS
13. General
W234
Pear
95
4
76
4
135
6
8
1


ATLANTIS
13. General
U7
Plum
986
7
23
7
5
3
8
2


ATLANTIS
13. General
V467
Peach
1011
4
65
9
43
6
6
1



...
SQL for doing that works fine:
SELECT County, Section, MeasureCode, MeasureDesc
    , MAX(CASE WHEN theValue = 'Members' THEN CAST([Overall] as int) ELSE 0 END) as [Overall Members]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN theValue = 'Percent' THEN CAST([Overall] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as [Overall Percent]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN theValue = 'Members' THEN CAST([65-74] as int) ELSE 0 END) as [65-74 Members]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN theValue = 'Percent' THEN CAST([65-74] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as [65-74 Percent]
    
    , MAX(CASE WHEN theValue = 'Members' THEN CAST([75-84] as int) ELSE 0 END) as [75-84 Members]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN theValue = 'Percent' THEN CAST([75-84] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as [75-84 Percent]
    
    , MAX(CASE WHEN theValue = 'Members' THEN CAST([85+] as int) ELSE 0 END) as [85+ Members]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN theValue = 'Percent' THEN CAST([85+] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as [85+ Percent]
    
FROM (
        SELECT 'Members' as theValue
            , County, Section, MeasureCode, MeasureDesc
            , [Overall], [65-74], [75-84], [85+]
        FROM #cond a
        PIVOT(SUM(MemberCount)
            FOR AgeBand IN ([Overall], [Under 65], [65-74], [75-84], [85+])
            ) b

        UNION
        SELECT 'Percent' as theValue
            , County, Section, MeasureCode, MeasureDesc
            , [Overall], [65-74], [75-84], [85+]
        FROM #cond a
        PIVOT(MAX(PctTotal)
            FOR AgeBand IN ([Overall], [65-74], [75-84], [85+])
            ) c
    ) e
    
GROUP BY County, Section, MeasureCode, MeasureDesc
ORDER BY Section
    , MAX(CASE WHEN Section = '13. Another Section' THEN CAST(MeasureDesc as int)
                        WHEN theValue = 'Percent' THEN CAST([Overall] as decimal(10,2))
                        WHEN theValue = 'Members' THEN CAST([Overall] as decimal(10,2))
                        ELSE 0 
                END) DESC

As you can see though, in the original data set, there is a column for Gender. I want to add that as a SubCategory of the AgeBands so that it will look like this (added color and borders to make it more clear):
(Note that each age band section now has Female and Male sub-divisions - sorry, Table Markup can't do merged cells, which would make this more clear)



County
Section
Code
Desc
Overall
Overall
Overall
Overall
65-74
65-74
65-74
65-74
75-84
75-84
75-84
75-84
85+
85+
85+
85+




-
-
-
-
Female
Female
Male
Male
Female
Female
Male
Male
Female
Female
Male
Male
Female
Female
Male
Male


-
-
-
-
Count
%
Count
%
Count
%
Count
%
Count
%
Count
%
Count
%
Count
%


ATLANTIS
13. General
F34
Apple
876
5
876
5
74
3
74
3
96
1
96
1
9
2
9
2


ATLANTIS
13. General
H84
Orange
876
7
876
7
67
7
67
7
86
4
86
4
6
1
6
1


ATLANTIS
13. General
W234
Pear
95
4
95
4
76
4
76
4
135
6
135
6
8
1
8
1


ATLANTIS
13. General
U7
Plum
986
7
986
7
23
7
23
7
5
3
5
3
8
2
8
2


ATLANTIS
13. General
V467
Peach
1011
4
1011
4
65
9
65
9
43
6
43
6
6
1
6
1



However, I'm am completely stuck on how to approach that in the SQL. Can someone point my in the correct direction?

Fixed ... though unfortunately Table Markdown doesn't do merged cells, so it's not quite as clear.  :/

I guess we can't have 2 column header for a SQL result. But you can add few more lines to your code as below?
    SELECT County, Section, MeasureCode, MeasureDesc
    , MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Members' And MemberGender = 'F') THEN CAST([Overall] as int) ELSE 0 END) as [F_Overall Members]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Members' And MemberGender = 'M') THEN CAST([Overall] as int) ELSE 0 END) as [M_Overall Members]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Percent' And MemberGender = 'F') THEN CAST([Overall] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as [F_Overall Percent]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Percent' And MemberGender = 'M') THEN CAST([Overall] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as [M_Overall Percent]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Members' And MemberGender = 'F') THEN CAST([65-74] as int) ELSE 0 END) as [F_65-74 Members]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Members' And MemberGender = 'M') THEN CAST([65-74] as int) ELSE 0 END) as [M_65-74 Members]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Percent' And MemberGender = 'F') THEN CAST([65-74] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as [F_65-74 Percent]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Percent' And MemberGender = 'M') THEN CAST([65-74] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as [M_65-74 Percent]
    
    , MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Members' And MemberGender = 'F') THEN CAST([75-84] as int) ELSE 0 END) as [F_75-84 Members]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Members' And MemberGender = 'M') THEN CAST([75-84] as int) ELSE 0 END) as [M_75-84 Members]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Percent' And MemberGender = 'F') THEN CAST([75-84] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as [F_75-84 Percent]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Percent' And MemberGender = 'M') THEN CAST([75-84] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as [M_75-84 Percent]
    
    , MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Members' And MemberGender = 'F') THEN CAST([85+] as int) ELSE 0 END) as [F_85+ Members]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Members' And MemberGender = 'M') THEN CAST([85+] as int) ELSE 0 END) as [M_85+ Members]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Percent' And MemberGender = 'F') THEN CAST([85+] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as [F_85+ Percent]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Percent' And MemberGender = 'M') THEN CAST([85+] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as [M_85+ Percent]
    
FROM (
        SELECT 'Members' as theValue
            , County, Section, MeasureCode, MeasureDesc, MemberGender
            , [Overall], [65-74], [75-84], [85+]
        FROM #cond a
        PIVOT(SUM(MemberCount)
            FOR AgeBand IN ([Overall], [Under 65], [65-74], [75-84], [85+])
            ) b

        UNION
        SELECT 'Percent' as theValue
            , County, Section, MeasureCode, MeasureDesc, MemberGender
            , [Overall], [65-74], [75-84], [85+]
        FROM #cond a
        PIVOT(MAX(PctTotal)
            FOR AgeBand IN ([Overall], [65-74], [75-84], [85+])
            ) c
    ) e
    
GROUP BY County, Section, MeasureCode, MeasureDesc, MemberGender
ORDER BY Section
    , MAX(CASE WHEN Section = '13. Another Section' THEN CAST(MeasureDesc as int)
                        WHEN theValue = 'Percent' THEN CAST([Overall] as decimal(10,2))
                        WHEN theValue = 'Members' THEN CAST([Overall] as decimal(10,2))
                        ELSE 0 
                END) DESC


For having secondary level column header within SQL grid result, you can try doing something like below,
Select '' Country, '' Section, '', '' [Desc]    , 'Female Count' Overall    , 'Female %' Overall    , 'Male Count' Overall  , 'Male %' Overall  , 'Female Count' [65-74]    , 'Female %' [65-74]    , 'Male Count' [65-74]  , 'Male %' [65-74]  , 'Female Count' [75-84]    , 'Female %' [75-84]    , 'Male Count' [75-84]  , 'Male %' [75-84]  , 'Female Count' [85+]  , 'Female %' [85+]  , 'Male Count' [85+]    , 'Male %' [85+]

Union

SELECT County, Section, MeasureCode, MeasureDesc
    , Cast(MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Members' And MemberGender = 'F') THEN CAST([Overall] as int) ELSE 0 END) as varchar) as [F_Overall Members]
    , Cast(MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Members' And MemberGender = 'M') THEN CAST([Overall] as int) ELSE 0 END) as varchar) as [M_Overall Members]
    , Cast(MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Percent' And MemberGender = 'F') THEN CAST([Overall] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as varchar) as [F_Overall Percent]
    , Cast(MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Percent' And MemberGender = 'M') THEN CAST([Overall] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as varchar) as [M_Overall Percent]
    , Cast(MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Members' And MemberGender = 'F') THEN CAST([65-74] as int) ELSE 0 END) as varchar) as [F_65-74 Members]   , Cast(MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Members' And MemberGender = 'M') THEN CAST([65-74] as int) ELSE 0 END) as varchar) as [M_65-74 Members]
    , Cast(MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Percent' And MemberGender = 'F') THEN CAST([65-74] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as varchar) as [F_65-74 Percent]     , Cast(MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Percent' And MemberGender = 'M') THEN CAST([65-74] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as varchar) as [M_65-74 Percent]
    
    , Cast(MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Members' And MemberGender = 'F') THEN CAST([75-84] as int) ELSE 0 END) as varchar) as [F_75-84 Members]   , Cast(MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Members' And MemberGender = 'M') THEN CAST([75-84] as int) ELSE 0 END) as varchar) as [M_75-84 Members]
    , Cast(MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Percent' And MemberGender = 'F') THEN CAST([75-84] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as varchar) as [F_75-84 Percent]     , Cast(MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Percent' And MemberGender = 'M') THEN CAST([75-84] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as varchar) as [M_75-84 Percent]
    
    , Cast(MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Members' And MemberGender = 'F') THEN CAST([85+] as int) ELSE 0 END) as varchar) as [F_85+ Members]   , Cast(MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Members' And MemberGender = 'M') THEN CAST([85+] as int) ELSE 0 END) as varchar) as [M_85+ Members]
    , Cast(MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Percent' And MemberGender = 'F') THEN CAST([85+] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as varchar) as [F_85+ Percent]     , Cast(MAX(CASE WHEN (theValue = 'Percent' And MemberGender
= 'M') THEN CAST([85+] as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END) as varchar) as [M_85+ Percent]
     FROM (
        SELECT 'Members' as theValue
            , County, Section, MeasureCode, MeasureDesc, MemberGender
            , [Overall], [65-74], [75-84], [85+]
        FROM #cond a
        PIVOT(SUM(MemberCount)
            FOR AgeBand IN ([Overall], [Under 65], [65-74], [75-84], [85+])
            ) b

        UNION
        SELECT 'Percent' as theValue
            , County, Section, MeasureCode, MeasureDesc, MemberGender
            , [Overall], [65-74], [75-84], [85+]
        FROM #cond a
        PIVOT(MAX(PctTotal)
            FOR AgeBand IN ([Overall], [65-74], [75-84], [85+])
            ) c
    ) e
     GROUP BY County, Section, MeasureCode, MeasureDesc, MemberGender ORDER BY Section
    , MAX(CASE WHEN Section = '13. Another Section' THEN CAST(MeasureDesc as int)
                        WHEN theValue = 'Percent' THEN CAST([Overall] as decimal(10,2))
                        WHEN theValue = 'Members' THEN CAST([Overall] as decimal(10,2))
                        ELSE 0 
                END) DESC

